# How do I fix my inbound messages to Twilio from being split?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms, twilio

I'm sending a text message to my Twilio number and it's getting split into two messages.  I believe it's happening because there are unicode characters in it.  I understand that.

However, I don't know how to fix this issue.  After I send this text message from my phone to my Twilio number, Twilio will make a post request to a route in my Rails app and I don't really know how to have it make that post request with those unicode characters.

Any ideas on what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you are getting two incoming webhooks for the one message you send? Could you send the message SIDs to me at philnash@twilio.com? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adjust and plan for this...it's happening because the messages are exceeding the character limit: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/why-are-my-messages-with-unicode-being-split

Comment: The link you reference seems to be referring to outbound messages (from Twilio to a phone number). I'm referring to inbound messages that are getting split up. How do I adjust for this and for the variability in text messages someone might respond with?

Comment: You could try grouping them by phone number and finding messages sent very close together (and/or by id) to make sure you have the entire message. Here's their q&a about limitations: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-many-calls-and-sms-messages-per-second-can-my-twilio-account-make?baseUrl=%2Fhelp%2F

Comment: Inbound and Outbound messages are the same. They both have the same character limit. Outbound messages twilio breaks up, inbound messages your carrier breaks up. Either way you will have to account for that somehow and do as @toddmetheny suggested